# Invalid column errow with dynamic SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server

I want to write dynamic tsql, but system returns error 'invalid column' why?

```
DECLARE @WhereClause NVARCHAR(2000) 
DECLARE @SelectStatement NVARCHAR(2000)
DECLARE @FullStatement NVARCHAR(4000) 

set @WhereClause = 'elad' 
SET @SelectStatement = 'SELECT TOP 1 * FROM elad where  '
SET @FullStatement = @SelectStatement +'last_name'+'='+@WhereClause 

EXECUTE sp_executesql @FullStatement
```

In this query I expect that system to return all row that last name field is equal to elad,
but system returns:

> Msg 207, Level 16, State 1, Line 1
>   Invalid column name 'elad'.'

Comment: Your SQL statement results in `SELECT TOP 1 * FROM elad WHERE last_name = elad` and thus the `WHERE` clause attempts to compare the `last_name` column to an `elad` column - which of course doesn't exist. You need to put your string literals into **single quotes!** ....

Comment: When you have issues with a dynamic query, write the correct *static* version of it, change the script that builds the dynamic query so that it **prints** the query instead of executing it. Look at the printed result and compare to the correct static version. If you can't resolve the issue, *then* ask about it, showing us what the query *should* look like too (don't make us guess!).

Answer (score 1):

You need to add quotes in your Where clause

```
SET @FullStatement = @SelectStatement +'last_name'+'='''+@WhereClause + ''''
```

Comment: @GrzegorzGierlik The answer was strictly on what is wrong syntactically with the question. Of course it is better to use `sp_executesql`